# Using spring cloud feign when http code is 401, the respose.body() is null

Tags: netflix-feign, spring-cloud-feign

Using the spring cloud feign call my service, when the service return 401 exception, the `respose.body()` is null.

When I throw the exception that is `throw new BadRequestException(400， “this http code is 400”);` I can get the error message that `this http code is 400` by `response.body()`.
But when I throw the exception `throw new BadRequestException(401， “this http code is 401”);`, the `response.body()` is null.
This response is `feign.Response`.

Why I can`t get this error message when http code is 401?

Hope your help! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Switch to feign-okhttp will fix your problem.

Add in Pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.netflix.feign</groupId>
    <artifactId>feign-okhttp</artifactId>
    <version>8.18.0</version>
</dependency>
```

And add in your config:

```
feign.okhttp.enabled: true
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! using `ApacheHttpClient` is also ok. Can you tell me why HttpUrlConnection close the error stream why error code is 401 or 407?

Answer (score 0):

I switched the default http client implementation to ApacheHttpClient and it works

Maven dependency:

```
 <dependency>
  <groupId>io.github.openfeign</groupId>
  <artifactId>feign-httpclient</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

application:

```
 feign.httpclient.enabled: true
```

Spring bean

```
@Bean
Client client(){
   return new ApacheHttpClient();
}
```

As suggested in https://codingnconcepts.com/spring-boot/change-default-feign-client-implementation/